# is there something wrong with my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

```
Player.prototype.collide=function(){
  if(this.velocity>0){
    if(
      (this.y+this.velocity+playerHeight)>=platform1.y 
      && this.x>platform1.x 
      && (this.x+playerWidth)<(platform.x+100)
    ){
      flag=1;
    }
  }
}
```

this is a method of prototype Player which detects if it has hit the platform.After the player jumps and when it's falling if it hits the platform the flag is supposed to turn 1.for that first it must test whether is falling back to the ground after it jumps.after that it must check if it has hit the platform.but this certain function has messed up my whole code.if anyone's willing to help i can upload my working code..

Comment: if the player hit the platform wouldn't his velocity be 0

Comment: There's nothing except your conditions that could break this one. Check if they're correct.

Comment: You are missing a ; at the end of the function declaration.

Comment: this.x>platform1.x ... (this.x+playerWidth)<(platform.x+100) ... is that a typo (platform.x vs platform1.x)

Comment: @AmirGeri - optional ; wont stop it from working

Comment: The word _velocity_ implies a _vector_, not just a _speed_. Are you sure that the velocity is pointing along the _y_ axis? Also, you probably want the player width on the left of the platform, not the right.

Comment: @JaromandaX oh yeah thanks. it was a typo. but still not working even after the correction

Comment: @depperm well when the player's falling it's velocity is positive.if it hits the platform then turning the flag to 1 will make the velocity 0.

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!y1wSDRgL!9IcfbePilw9xEVOOkeh_pmCxl3OjP1QxYPgDuqXUYpk

Comment: here's the link to my files. please open the shadow-copy.html ;it doesn't have the collide function yet but it works and it also has explainations. the function collide is included in the shadow-copy2.html . AFTER OPENING THE HTML FILE PLEASE PRESS THE GAME OPTIONS WHEN THEY ARE ON THE LEFT SIDE OTHERWISE THEY WONT RESPOND https://mega.co.nz/#!y1wSDRgL!9IcfbePilw9xEVOOkeh_pmCxl3OjP1QxYPgDuqXUYpk